# iframe not Rendering in .NET ReportViewer Web Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, reporting-services

I have a .NET Webform ReportViewer control. When I run it locally everything is fine. But when deployed to a server it won't render. debugging on the browser shows that the iframe that handles everything is simply not present.

this is all in a custom control that was here before my time. So basically when the render method is called the custom control adds the controls to a panel control, then uses the HTMLWriter class so create a div, calls .Render() and then passes in the HTMLwriter. I used string comparison to see if the iframe was somehow being sanitized(for security)  by the browser, but it is not. I have verified the server has v 8,9, and 10 of both ReportViewer.Common and ReportViewer.Webform. I have tried referencing all of these in my web.config and msproj references and still no joy. Its the weirdest thing, same microsoft library, 2 different boxes, writes two different HTML strings.

Anyone seen anything like this. I have definitely checked through SO and found most of it has to do with the missing assemblies from the GAC, but I am seeing all of them present. Environment issues are so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this was an environment issue after all and had nothing to do with the code. The custom control that contained the report viewer control was blocking it from allowing errors to bubble up since it was directly writing the render to HTML. It turned out to be Report Server permissions.